# FlaskApp has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, swagger, flask-sqlalchemy

all. I writing project using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and connexion. Before connexion was implemented, all works success (p.s. when app created as `app = Flask(__name__)`. After implementing connexion raises an exception:
`'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' not in app.config and AttributeError: 'FlaskApp' object has no attribute 'config'`. So where is a mistake? Help, please.

run.py:

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app('development')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

app:

```
...
from settings import app_config
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app(config_name):
    # app = Flask(__name__)
    app = connexion.App(__name__)
    app.add_api('swagger.yml')
    application = app.app
    application.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

settings.py

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET = os.getenv('SECRET', 'default_secret_key')
    DEFAULT_URI = 'postgresql://shooter:shooter@localhost/shooterstats'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DEFAULT_URI

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a mistake here `db.init_app(app)`. I changed it to db.init_app(application) and it is working success now.

Comment: Why it works? I do not get it honestly and your comment therefore is also not that helpful as it should. Could you please add exact reasoning please?

Comment: When using connexion the flask app is being wrapped. To access the flask app use `app.app`. SQLAlchemy must call the db.init_app() on the flask app, not the connexion app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can set up your Flask application with Connexion.

```
import connexion

# This creates the connexion application instance.
connexion_app = connexion.App(__name__)
# This gets the underlying Flask app instance.
flask_app = connexion_app.app  # Flask(__name__)
```